# How do I solve the AWSSecurityTokenServiceException error in Databricks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, databricks, roles, aws-databricks

I have been trying to read some data from an AWS S3 bucket to Databricks.  The S3 bucket is **development/team/user**.  I am using the Scala statement:

```
val test = spark.read.format("team").load("/mnt/development/team/user/data.txt")
```

and I get the following:

> com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: User [user] is not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRole on resource: [resource]

How do I resolve this error?  Is there a problem with the Databricks cluster I am running?  Is there a way to allow my Databricks role to perform sts:AssumeRole in AWS?  I am not sure if or how I can do either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have done this before.
Here you are getting this error because STS assumes a role you can set up by selecting STS policy in the role while creating policy and you can update the trust relationship also.

This link will help you https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=266814

Comment: Thank you.  I will check out the link.